# 'Error: TypeError: ProtractorImageComparison is not a constructor' with the protractor-image-comparison v2.0.1

Tags: javascript, visual-testing

I'm trying to write some visual tests and running into the mentioned error with the protractor-image-comparison of version 2.0.1. Even though there is an update of the library I decided to stick to the older version since I experience some issues with the newest one as well. 
My setup is:

//protractor.conf.js:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
const { join } = require('path');
const { ProtractorImageComparison } = require('protractor-image-comparison');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: ['./src/**/*-spec.ts'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        // '--headless',
        '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1600,950', '--no-sandbox'],
    },
  },
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {
    },
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json'),
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));

    browser.protractorImageComparison = new ProtractorImageComparison({
      baselineFolder: join(__dirname, '/src/resources/baseline/'),
      screenshotPath: join(__dirname, '/src/tmp/'),
      formatImageName: '{tag}',
      autoSaveBaseline: false
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue today and apparently from [version 3.0.1](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-image-comparison/releases/tag/3.0.1) this package now functions as a plugin and not a class which needs to be instantiated.

I managed to get it working adding the following code to my conf.js:

```
plugins: [
    {
        inline: require('protractor-image-comparison'),
        // package: 'protractor-image-comparison' //protractor is installed globally so it is checking for plugin globally also
        options: {
            baselineFolder: './testArtifacts/screen-compare/baselines/',
            screenshotPath: './testArtifacts/screen-compare/screenshots/',
            formatImageName: `{tag}-{logName}-{width}x{height}`,
            savePerInstance: true,
        },
    },
],
```

**Note:** For me protractor was installed globally so I needed this workaround using `inline` instead of `package` to get it searching for the plugin module locally.